# 1997 Honda accord will not start

Tags: honda, starting, shifting, power-windows

I have a 1997 Honda accord. The other day I had it started and turned it off went to start it up again and nothing just a click. When I go to start it the battery indicator light comes on and will not try to turn over.my shifter is locked in park, my windows will not roll down, sun roof will not open.but on the other hand the a/c comes on, the lights work,and the radio works.I know its not the starter,I checked all my fuses in and out the car. I need help can some one tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Have you attempted to jump-start the car? It sounds like the battery is dead through your description.

Comment: Yes I did it did not work

Comment: Regarding your windows, did you test them with your key in both the ignition *and* the accessory position?

Comment: I did try both in the accel position and the crank

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of this, regarding your windows, is your p/w lock on?

Comment: What size engine? Recheck the ignition switch fuse 50A in the underhood fuse box. I'm betting this is blown/the wiring to the ignition switch is bad/the ignition switch is bad. Check the Battery fuse as well either 80A or 100A.